# Why E[XY|W = w] = E[X|W = w]* E[Y|W = w] is true when X an Y are Two conditionally independent discrete random variables and W is a random discretevar

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Why E[XY|W = w] = E[X|W = w]* E[Y|W = w] is true when X an Y are Two conditionally independent discrete random variables and W is a random discrete variable ?

if X and Y are conditionally independent given W = w, then why E[XY|W = w] = E[X|W = w]* E[Y|W = w]

How do we even calculate E[XY|W = w] ?

Comment: "conditionally independent discrete random variables" means $\mathbb P(X=x,Y=y \mid W=w) = \mathbb P(X=x \mid W=w)\mathbb P(Y=y \mid W=w)$ so use this to find the conditional expectations

Comment: $\mathbb E(XY \mid W=w) = \sum\limits_x \sum\limits_y \,x\, y\, \mathbb P(X=x,Y=y \mid W=w)$